# how to parse this kind of json array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, web

I have a json array like blew :

```
    {
    "0": {
        "kind": "mammal",
        "name": "Pussy the Cat",
        "weight": "12kg",
        "age": "5"
    },
    "1": {
        "kind": "mammal",
        "name": "Roxy the Dog",
        "weight": "25kg",
        "age": "8"
    },
    "2": {
        "kind": "fish",
        "name": "Piranha the Fish",
        "weight": "1kg",
        "age": "1"
    },
    "3": {
        "kind": "bird",
        "name": "Einstein the Parrot",
        "weight": "0.5kg",
        "age": "4"
    }
}
```

i removed an element 'Piranha the Fish' With (UNSET) My json code changed to blow:

```
{
    "0": {
        "kind": "mammal",
        "name": "Pussy the Cat",
        "weight": "12kg",
        "age": "5"
    },
    "1": {
        "kind": "mammal",
        "name": "Roxy the Dog",
        "weight": "25kg",
        "age": "8"
    },
    "3": {
        "kind": "bird",
        "name": "Einstein the Parrot",
        "weight": "0.5kg",
        "age": "4"
    }
}
```

when I remove element the counter of the element change to 0,1,3
so now i can't to have full access in my json elements

I want echo value with this code :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $JsonCount - 1; $i++) {
    echo "Name :";
    echo $json_cod[$i]['name'];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Age :";
    echo $json_cod[$i]['age'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

out put :

```
Name :Pussy the Cat
Age :5
Name :Roxy the Dog
Age :8
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Your data structure does not look like a JSON array. Are you sure that's what you're trying to parse?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: Use `foreach` the index can be ignored

Comment: Either re-index the array in PHP _before_ you encode it as JSON; or use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Your code only gives the illusion of having assoc arrays inside a numeric array. Somewhere you convert your numeric array ;)

Comment: You loop is written in php, so why are you using json in the 1st place? Please give more context for a useful answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `foreach`.

```
foreach ($json_cod as $item) {
  echo "Name :";echo $item['name'];echo "<br/>";
  echo "Age :";echo $item['age'];echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your code to echo ,after deleting a value from array use `$newarray=array_values($oldarray)` to reindex the array.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `unset()` remove the value along with the key/index from the array and left it as it is,i.e it does not  rearrange the key/index.

If you want to rearrange key the use `array_slice()` instead See [array_slice](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_slice.asp). and you will get what you want. You will be able to do

```
for($i=0; $i <$JsonCount-1 ; $i++)
{
    echo "Name :";echo $json_cod[$i]['name'];echo "<br/>";
    echo "Age :";echo $json_cod[$i]['age'];echo "<br/>";
}
```